# laravel collection nested "where"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

Assume the following collection:

```
 [
   order
    -id
    -receiverAddress
    -...
    relations
        transactions
            -id
            -transaction_id_external
            - ...
 ]
```

I tried to use the following filter on the collection:

```
    $isNotEmpty = $orders->filter(function ($order) use ($receivedPaymentDetails) {
        return $order->transactions
            ->where('transaction_id_external', $receivedPaymentDetails->txid)
            ->where('order.receiverAddress', $receivedPaymentDetails->address)
            ->isNotEmpty();
    })->isNotEmpty();
```

It seems like this doesn't work, any idea how I can filter on the parent collection item order.receiverAddress?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to filter based on the transactions relations, you must perform some form of join query with your transactions table

Easiest way for you would be to place your queries in a whereHas callback

```
$isNotEmpty = $orders->filter(function ($order) use ($receivedPaymentDetails) {
            return $order->whereHas('transactions', function ($query) use ($receivedPaymentDetails) {
                $query->where('transactions.transaction_id_external', $receivedPaymentDetails->txid);
                $query->where('order.receiverAddress', $receivedPaymentDetails->address);
            })
                ->isNotEmpty();
        })->isNotEmpty();
```

Comment: But the data is already available, isn't there a chance I can use plain collection methods to filter (without using another SQL query)?

Comment: @gamedev If you are selecting the transactions table, you will only be able to query based on the data inside that table, and therefore, you must join the order table with the transactions table if you want to query on values from both tables

Comment: Oh okay, there is no way to do so using pure collection operations?

Comment: Well, a collection is an array at the end of the day, and is not able to on it's own perform neccessary SQL actions needed.

Comment: Thought it would be able using: [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods)